# angularJS checkbox not updating the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox and I want to check its value on submit:

html:

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="AddUserForm" ng-submit="submit(AddUserForm)">
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="adduser-email" class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2 control-label">email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xl-10">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="adduser-email" ng-model="AddUserForm.email" required>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xl-12">
                <input id="adduser-mailinglist" type="checkbox" ng-model="AddUserForm.mailinglist">Add to mailing list</input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-10">
                    <button class="blue-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add User</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The JS:

```
    $scope.submit = function(AddUserForm) {
        console.log(AddUserForm.mailinglist);
    };
```

I'm getting `undefined`

The text input is fine and exists in the form model

Made a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NKow0isUCp8PZy90drmA

Comment: Would be nice if you could create a Fiddle or so. Does this happen after have interacted with the checkbox? Maybe you need to assign the model an initial value.

Comment: Does `console.log(AddUserForm)` display anything in the console?

Comment: Yes. And values of the text elements in the form are correct. Only the checkbox value is missing

Comment: I'm afraid it works fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0iWYgVLwU3YScFnYHTnM?p=preview).

Comment: @Blazemonger - you get an undefined as well...

Comment: Not if I check and un-check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0ukwaug4/

Here's the update html, update submit(AddUserForm) to just submit(), the object is already defined in the scope level:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="AddUserForm" ng-submit="submit()">
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="adduser-email" class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2 control-label">email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xl-10">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="adduser-email" ng-model="AddUserForm.email" required>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xl-12">
                <input id="adduser-mailinglist" type="checkbox" ng-model="AddUserForm.mailinglist">Add to mailing list</input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-10">
                    <button class="blue-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add User</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The javascript:

```
    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.AddUserForm.mailinglist);    
    };
```

You'll get `undefined` when it is unchecked, but it'll be `true` when it is checked.

gl

Comment: I'm getting undefined even if I check it

Comment: in my plukr as well, the thing is that in the original code even a checked checkbox gives me undefined... weird...

Comment: In the original code, you are not using dot notation. The creates `mailinglist` on the view's scope and not the controller. Use dot notation or controller as.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the checkbox's model in your controller:

```
$scope.mailinglist = false;
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9dPhXiqqMogIje4o6UFm?p=preview)

Comment: I agree with you that the plunkr works... My original code doesn't. Can it be related to the face that it's a modalInstance?

Comment: No this is just a very unusual issue with checkbox models in Angular that (I believe) should be fixed. If you click on it and then click again and submit, it'll come in as "false". It seems the $scope doesn't see it, unless it's set (like above) or changed. @Boaz

Answer (score 0):

As others have already provided a working plnkr, I will just let you know why your original didn't work. When creating properties without using dot notation, i.e. `mailinglist` instead of `AddUserForm.mailinglist` you are creating this property on the view's scope instead of getting the controller's scope. Use dot notation or Controller As to get at the controller's scope.

Check out this video by Egghead.IO for a more thorough explanation:
[AngularJS - The Dot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc)

Comment: That's a good point, Owen. And indeed the original code was AddUserForm.mailinglist. the mailinglist version is for making sure there aren't problems woth the form model

Comment: Ah, I was going off the plnkr in your original post. In that plnkr, you defined `$scope.mailinglist` in the controller, but only `mailinglist` on the view. This is what created the child scope version of `mailinglist`. As far as the dot notation version, if you haven't defined `AddUserForm.mailinglist` as true or false, it will resolve as undefined until the first model change. This is just the joy of JavaScript. The simple way is to initialize values for `AddUserForm` to have `.mailinglist` as false.